# Getting position of seekbar from recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, seekbar

quick question since my other question never got answered. I have a `RecyclerView` which gets populated with a `SeekBar` for every item (`CardView`). I would like to know the best way to get this `SeekBar`'s position.

In other words, how would I be able to differentiate the first seekbar from the second seekbar if there are two items in the recyclerview each containing its own `SeekBar`?

Also, if this helps any, the listener for said `SeekBar` is in my Adapter.

Sample of code upon request:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView mName, mUsername, mPercent;
    private SeekBar mSeekBar;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_view_members);
        mUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username_view_members);
        mPercent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_text);
        mSeekBar = (SeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.percent_seekbar);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    GroupMembers individual = mMembers.get(position);
    holder.mName.setText(individual.getName());
    holder.mUsername.setText(individual.getUsername());

    //SeekBar Listener
    holder.mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            //Find out which SeekBar triggered the event
            int which = whichIsIt(seekBar.getId(), progress);

            //Stored progress (where is it at)
            int storedProgress = mAllProgress.get(which);

            /**Two cases can occur: User goes left or right with the thumb.
             * If RIGHT, we must check how much he's allowed to go in that
             * direction (based on other seekbars), and stop him before it's
             * too late. If LEFT, free up the space to allow the other seekbars.
             **/
            if (progress > storedProgress) {
                //How much remains based on all seekbars.
                int remaining = remaining();
                //If progress 100%, don't let user move. (overextend)
                if (remaining == 0) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(storedProgress);
                } else {
                    //Progress available, check the availability of others,
                    //and let the user move as long as it's below 100% total.
                    if (storedProgress + remaining >= progress) {
                        mAllProgress.set(which, progress);
                    } else {
                        mAllProgress.set(which, storedProgress + remaining);
                    }
                }
            } else if (progress <= storedProgress) {
                mAllProgress.set(which, progress);
            }
        }

        private int whichIsIt(int id, int progress) {
            holder.mPercent.setText(" " + progress + "%");
            return R.id.percent_seekbar;
        }

        private int remaining() {
            int remaining = TOTAL_AMOUNT;
            for (int i = 0; i < mAllProgress.size(); i++) {
                remaining -= mAllProgress.get(i);
            }
            if (remaining >= 100) {
                remaining = 100;
            } else if (remaining <= 0) {
                remaining = 0;
            }
            return remaining;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });
```

The method `whichIsIt` should determine which `SeekBar` of the `RecyclerView` is being triggered.

Comment: post your sample of code

Comment: @raj I edited/added the sample code above. Any help would be much appreciated...I've been stuck for quite a while.

Comment: @AndrewMagana I have multiple seekbars and when I Scroll previous one it changes audio how to prevent it  .?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a tag for each seekBar with the position in the adapter `seekBar.setTag(holderPosition);`

So in the method  `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,...)` you do `seekBar.getTag()`. This way you can change your data in the right position.

P.S: If OnSeekBarChangeListener is the same for all seekBars you can create a private field with it. ;)

Comment: This got me a step closer, and it techincally answers the question I had. Quick question...when I use `seekBar.getTag()`  in my `storedProcess` it gives an error every time I try to move a seekbar other than the first position. Why is this? Would `getTag` not simply grab the position touched since that's the tag I set (holder position)?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it was not relevant to the getTag. Thank you for your help!